# Is it possible to create a button to download all files attached to a record?

Tags: apex, lightning, community, files

Currently, we have a page on our community in which people can go in and look at our cases and see and download all of the files attached to the case. That said, we recently got a request to create a button that will allow them to download all of the files attached to the case at once, rather then individually downloading them one at a time. At face value this seems like it should be easy, but the more I think about it the less sure I am of how I would do it. I see there is some ideas on it that imply that it is not possible in the standard salesforce functionality, but am still wondering if it can be done using some of the development tools.

My current thought is to have a button that upon click sends a call through the JS controller to the Server side controller and asks to query for all of the content documents linked to this record. Fairly straightforward. Then I think it should send the list of files back through the JS to the Aura component via a callback. However, once it is there, all I have is the file ID, which I am not confident I can really utilize as I will need to in the component itself and have no idea how I would go about doing so.

In essence, I suppose this breaks into two key questions-

1. Is it possible to do this at all? Does the salesforce system support this in any way, even if it may not be through the lightning component system I had in mind?
2. If so, where and how does this occur? Does the download functionality live in the Javascript controller, or the actual component itself? Where can I find any documentation on the method that is needed, if it exists?

Again, I am not married to the idea that I outlined above, but figured it was useful for context, so if anyone knows a better way to do this outside of that, I am open to any ideas, as long as it ends with the files being downloaded in a single click or two.

Comment: Are you ok using an AppExchange app to address your requirements? if yes, then there's a paid app available on AppExchange **Mass File Download**, its perfect solution to mass-download files/attachments related to a record or multiple records in just 1-2 clicks. 

Check out app @ https://sforce.co/34thF8U

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it would be possible easily in lightning.

The sessionID in lightning is not API enabled, Thus you cannot access standard rest endpoint to download files. On top of that you cannot make calls to RestEndpont from javascript.

> You can’t make Salesforce API calls from JavaScript code. For security
>   reasons, the Lightning Component framework places restrictions on
>   making API calls from JavaScript code. To call third-party APIs from
>   your component’s JavaScript code, add the API endpoint as a CSP
>   Trusted Site.
>
> To call Salesforce APIs, make the API calls from your component’s Apex
>   controller. Use a named credential to authenticate to Salesforce.

The one way you can do is, call that rest endpoint in APEX to download files using Named Credentials, But heap limit won't allow you to download large files.

So it is not straightforward path :/

I think building a chrome plugin that parses dom and then downloads all file would be easier.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/apex_api_calls.htm

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. Based on your assessment it definitely seems like the amount of effort required to make this work just isn't worth the trouble at the moment so I think I will recommend we hold off on this until we have some more time to play with outside tools. The chrome plugin is definitely a nice outside the box idea we might look into in the future, so the suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This may not be an answer, but will provide a context around achieving a "bulk download", which does not seem to be a straight forward solution.

If it was about downloading a single file from a lightning component, you could have done by using a combination of [force:navigateToURL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:navigateToURL/documentation) and utilizing the download URL which is in form of `https://<instance-url>/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/id-of-file`.

If the aforementioned URL worked with multiple *Ids*, then you could have utilized that approach, however that doesn't work. Furthermore, when you look towards downloading files in bulk, you will need to also consider how are you going to download all of those files --

1. Download independently

   OR
2. Zip all files and download as a single file.

You may still be in luck if you can Zip the files as one file and utilize the download URL as mentioned above, but this gets complicated when the file sizes are big. You will most likely hit the heap size limits while constructing the zip file in such scenarios.

In summary, this seems to be a good use case but seemingly complex to implement using platform capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to create server-side ZIP files in Apex. It's just not a feature supported by the platform and they don't provide any way to manipulate binary data at the level required to hand-roll an implementation. Plus you run into the issue of heap limits.

If it is possible for JavaScript to download each of the files into memory via an `XMLHttpRequest` to their URLs (and I'm not 100% sure that's allowed?), you could use a front-end ZIP library such as JSZip to stitch them all together and then offer the download to the end-user. Otherwise you could make individual calls to an Apex controller to pull down the data from each file (but be stuck by heap limits if any one file is big), and zip them on the front end.

Comment: When there's a will there's a way. This library creates ZIP files from Apex, but doing multiple files could run the risk of CPU Limits. https://github.com/pdalcol/Zippex

Comment: @ESRouter I stand by my assertion. Yes it technically can but the heap limits would mean it's not a practical answer to this question.

THAT BEING SAID... this would be a great use case for the upcoming Salesforce Functions feature.